# Hierarchical Grid with the items Drag and Drop functionality?

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, telerik, hierarchy

I'm wondering if there is out of the box control that supports both hierarchical data binding and in the same time items/rows drag and drop functionality can be implemented?!

I know that Telerik RadGrid supports the both functions
[Grid / Declarative Relations](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/declarativerelations/defaultcs.aspx) 
[Grid / Items Drag-and-drop](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/draganddrop/defaultcs.aspx)

but I don't know if I can use it implementing the both functionality or not? If so, how to implement this? Or if there are any other solution you have, please let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik Grid supports both functions.
[Here is a code sample for implementing drag and drop between flat (source) and hierarchical (target) grids.](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/grid/drag-and-drop-between-flat-and-hierarchical-grid.aspx)

The only issue with solution that it's only supported for RadControls version Q1 2010 and later.